# Maximum size of data received from JSON

Tags: iphone, json, nsurlconnection

I m making call to server using NSURLConnection for iPhone & receiving the response properly.

Just wanted to know how will I come to know wether the data I have received in JSON format is a complete JSON data & there will be no loss.

means, Will I ever get JSON data into 2 or many parts ?
If it gives complete result in 2 parts than what will be the maximum size of data I will receive in each part.

Thanks,
J61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP layer handles this. Unless something goes wrong, you will receive the complete reply from the server.